# Stroke Color Changed within the same Material?

Tags: materials, 2d

I am new to Blender, and Im using it for basic 2D animations. I was drawing something while suddenly I realized that the outline stroke has changed color. The old shapes in the same object and using the same material are still the dark, fully black color that I want. In this picture, the bottom is what I want (and what was happening) and the top is what is now being drawn. Both are a part of the same object and are the same material.
[image: The bottom is what I want (and what was happening) and the top is what is now being drawn]

Comment: Are the shapes in the same frame? Maybe you activated **onion skin** and are seeing a previous or a following frame. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/onion_skinning.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but no, this is all the same frame. Any new drawing or objects I add anywhere are now in that gray color too.